# JSESSIONID and ROUTEID cookies return with no domain via AJAX call

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, cookies, jsessionid

When making an ajax call to log a user in the response contains all my cookies but the JSESSIONID and ROUTEID cookies return with no domain.  Doing the same call as a regular request returns the cookies with the correct domain.  I can't seem to figure out why and searching seems to return no similar issues.

I use jQuery for my ajax call.

Comment: Is it from the same domain? If not, it may not work.

Comment: the page is http, the request is to https.  Both on the same domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to add

```
xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
},
```

as an ajax param
and

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
               request.getHeader("Origin"));
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

as my response headers